# Nested class is not loaded in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Pundit gem with Rails 5. Policy class looks like this:

```
class ModelPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end

  def index?
    ...
  end
end
```

Policies are in 'app/policies' folder, so they are autoloaded. With Rails 4 it worked as a charm but now I'm getting `NameError: uninitialized constant ModelPolicy::Scope`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. You need to define `Scope` class in `ApplicationPolicy` first.